# Application.cfc: this.debugipaddress and this.debuggingIPAddresses, what is the difference?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I've seen the following code (A list of ip addresses that need debugging) for Application.cfc:

```
<!---seen in blogs and perhaps earlier versions of CF documentation, livedocs isn't working for CF 7 & 8 for me tonight--->
<cfset this.debugipaddress = "192.168.1.15,192.168.1.27">
```

and

```
<!--- documented in CF 9 & 10--->
<cfset this.debuggingIPAddresses = "192.168.1.15,192.168.1.27">
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-750b.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-750b.html

I was wondering if there was a difference between the two variables?  I'm using ColdFusion 10, is one preferred over the other if they are the same?  Perhaps this.debugipaddress was deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can find it is a documentation bug.  According to Ray [Camden's blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/7/13/ColdFusion-9s-new-Application-variables) and the comments in it, it should be `debuggingipaddresses` not `debugipaddress`.  Ray also used it [here](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/Mobile/postDetail.cfm?post=C953380D-D8BF-3D95-44EE400F2B2E4168) and pointed out that there was a correction.

> Pretty standard and he appears to have nailed everything. A part of me
>   strongly wishes that Ben Forta would have never used UPPERCASE scope
>   names in the WACK books so that my eyes wouldn't have to bleed every
>   time I see someone else do that, but oh well :). **One minor correction
>   - this.debugipaddress is actually this.debuggingipaddresses ([see here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/7/13/ColdFusion-9s-new-Application-variables)) - no points deducted for that since it's a doc bug.** I also would have liked to have seen him mention the struct keys for smtpServerSettings
>   ({server="",username="",password=""}).